# Zend Pdf generation from an action

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-controller, zend-pdf

I have a controller Employee , in that i have the action detail . The detail action prints like the attached image.[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7bfae5ce57.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7bfae5ce57.png)

Suppose there is a save pdf button, i need to print this page as .pdf.. How can i do this ? Pls help me

Thanks in advance
Nisanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you would need to implement another view to Detail action, which would use all given information (as it does now for printing HTML) to create a PDF document. Then you could use [Context Switch](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) action helper to trigger using PDF View instead of what is displayed now.